# TextView visibility change notification

Tags: android-layout, textview, android

I need to detect when a `TextView` is made visible and when its made invisible. Is there any way to do this in Android? I've to make some processing when a `TextView` in my application changes visibility. Actually, it's visibility is being updated at a number of places and I'm looking to avoid calls at all of these places.

Comment: Use this:-For visible textview.setvisibilty(View.Visible) & for visibilty Gone textview.setvisibilty(View.Gone).

Comment: You set visibility yourself, there is no listener as far as I know for when the control is drawn on the UI. Change text or other proprieties of the TextView before you make the control visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will answer your question, but if you want to listen to textview visibility changes, I suggest customizing TextView and implement your own listener for it.

```
 public class TextViewExtension extends TextView {


     protected OnVisibilityChange mChangeListener = null;

     public interface OnVisibilityChange {
         void onChange(TextViewExtension mTextView, int mPrevVisibility, int mNewVisibility);
     }

     public TextViewExtension(Context context) {
         super(context);
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
     }

     /* (non-Javadoc)
      * @see android.view.View#setVisibility(int)
      */
     @Override
     public void setVisibility(int visibility) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.setVisibility(visibility);
         if (mChangeListener != null) {
             mChangeListener.onChange(this, getVisibility(), visibility);
         }
     }

     public void setOnVisibilityChange(OnVisibilityChange mChangeListener) {
         this.mChangeListener = mChangeListener;
     }
 }
```

[Here are examples for further implementation if you are curious](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Glad it helped :) , I suggest accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean textviewon=false;
if(textviewon){
textview.setvisibility(View.Visible);
}else
textview.setvisibility(View.Invisible);
```

put above condition in your code

Comment: Explanation/context always improves answers above providing code alone.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanation to it to make it look better.

Comment: ..also this just checks the current state. It doesn't listen for state change, which is what the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
visibility="gone"
```

in your xml fil